# Really confused about emits in Vue2. How do I sync two booleans between child and parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

From all the examples I have seen of child-to-parent handling in Vue2, it seems very straight forward
eg.

Child:

```
.$emit('some-event')
```

Parent:

```
<template>
    <child @some-event="doSomething"></child>
</template>
```

But I cannot get it to work.
In my case I just want to sync two booleans.

In my child component I have

```
data() {
  return {
    isUploading: false

  };
},
```

In my parent I have

```
data() {
  return {
    uploadStatus: false,
  };
},
```

I need to pass the boolean value to a second child, but to do this I first need it emitted to the parent. So basically, when isUploading is true, then uploadStatus should become true as well, but how am I supposed to do this?

I tried doing the emit in a computed function in the child component.

```
computed: {
  uploadBtn(){
    return this.$emit("child-upload-status")
  }
},
```

Then in the parent component I import it

```
<template>
    <child @child-upload-status="syncData()"></child>
</template>
```

and then I try to run a method where I sync the data

```
  syncData(){
    this.uploadStatus = this.isUploading
  }
```

This just returns "undefined"

So what am I supposed to do? My guess is I need to emit the computed function itself? The uploadBtn() function, but the documentation does not give me much to go on.

I just want uploadStatus on parent to change to whatever value isUploading on child is. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to do a little differently

#### 1. Use a watcher, not a computed property, in the child

This is because you want to *do* something, not just compute a value locally.

#### 2. Actively send the value from the child

Don't expect the boolean value to travel by itself - you have to send it. Put it as an extra parameter in `this.$emit`.

#### 3. In the parent, actively receive the value and act on it

In the `@` attribute that receives the message, give it the name of your handler function that will act on it. But don't *call* the function by putting parentheses `()`: just give the handler function's name.

I have changed the handler's name, to help this be self-documenting.

In that handler function, receive the parameter that has been emitted by the child, and act on it.

#### Example

Child:

```
watch: {
  isUploading(newValue){
       this.$emit("is-uploading-changed-to",newValue)
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
// in the template

<child @is-uploading-changed-to="childUploadingChangedTo" />


// in the script methods

childUploadingChangedTo(newVal){
    this.uploadStatus = newVal;
    console.log("Parent this.uploadStatus has changed to ",this.uploadStatus)
}
```

Obviously you don't need the console.log.

Once you can see that your parent `this.uploadStatus`, you can pass it as a parameter to the second child.

```
<second-child :uploadStatus="uploadStatus" />
```